# how to route all XML extension to a specific method codeigniter?

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, routes

I have codeigniter project. I want route all xml extension URL thorough a controller. if my URL get any .xml extension it will a redirect a specific controller method (because I have to check something ) after that it will load that .xml file. So I write

```
 $route['(.xml)'] = "home/xml";
```

Its redirect all .xml file to home/xml method properly iif that .xml file not exist in my project folder. If that .xml file exist in my project folder it didn't fire/execute home/xml, its directly load .xml file. So how can I get rid of this problem ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would go with `.htaccess` rule for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

into

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '.xml';
```

which is in your config.php file

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

Create a controller say example.php

with method test

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Example extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{

}

public function test()
{
     header( "Content-type: text/xml");

     echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
     <rss version='2.0'>
     <channel>
     <title RSS</title>
     <link>/</link>
     <description>Cloud RSS</description>
     <language>en-us</language>";

      // while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($con,$query)){
      //  $title=$row["title"];
      //  $link=$row["link"];
      //  $description=$row["description"];

       echo "<item>
       <title>Title</title>
       <link>Link</link>
       <description>description</description>
       </item>";
     // }
     echo "</channel></rss>";

}}
```

then in the routes add

`$route['example/(:any).xml'] = "example/test";`